# filter image names from image tags in php

Tags: php

here, only last image name is filtered.

it shows output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1532409837_pMsLIB1H.jpg );
```

how to get all image names?

```
$html='<p>werwerwer</p><table class="striped highlight responsive-table"><thead><tr><th>(header)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><p>(table)</p><p>dfsfsdf</p><p><br></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p><img src="./../../assets/media/temp/user_1/1532409254_iSQ0F95B.jpg"></p><p><br></p><p><img src="./../../assets/media/temp/user_1/1532409830_WaL9dI5B.jpg"></p><p><br></p><p>dfgdfg</p><p>sdad</p><p>sfsdf</p><p><br></p><p><img src="./../../assets/media/temp/user_1/1532409837_pMsLIB1H.jpg"><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>';

preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $html, $src);

$srcArray = array_pop($src);

foreach($srcArray as $src ){
    $imgName=explode('/',$src); 
    $fileName[]=end($imgName);      
}

print_r($fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case, i try like this,

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+\/?>/i',$html, $imageTags);                  
$allImageTags=join(',',$imageTags[0]);  
preg_match_all('#([^/\'"=]*?[.](?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png))\b#i',$allImageTags, $imageTags);
$imgSrcArray = array_pop($imageTags);
```

Comment: any body know another way please share

Answer (score 0):

Replace your regex for global search. Your regex returns after first match.

Use `/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/ig`

[regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

Comment: sorry, here show error like: 'preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'g''.